# Unable to run JOOQ GenerationTool with Java 11 (NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema)

Tags: java, jooq, java-11

I attempted to run the code gen with this command line as described in the documentation [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/code-generation/codegen-configuration/):

```
java -classpath "jooq-3.12.3.jar;jooq-meta-3.12.3.jar;jooq-codegen-3.12.3.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;." org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool library.xml
```

I get the following error:

```
Jan 10, 2020 5:10:45 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info
INFO: Initialising properties : library.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at org.jooq.util.jaxb.tools.MiniJAXB.getNamespace(MiniJAXB.java:389)
...
```

I'm using Java 11:

```
openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.5+10, mixed mode)
```

What am I missing?
PS. I'm very new to the world of Java...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is connected with removal of JAXB api as it was considered a part of JAVA EE API, thus removed form JDK since Java 9 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) question for details).

You can solve your problem by adding [jaxb-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1) jar to your classpath :

```
java -classpath "jooq-3.12.3.jar;jooq-meta-3.12.3.jar;jooq-codegen-3.12.3.jar;reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.0.7.jar;jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar" org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool library.xml
```

Notice that I also had to add [reactive-streams-1.0.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2) jar to the classpath (as the tutorial mentions).

And change the MySQL driver jar to your jar in the command I pasted. So the final command in your case will be :

```
java -classpath "jooq-3.12.3.jar;jooq-meta-3.12.3.jar;jooq-codegen-3.12.3.jar;reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar;mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar" org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool library.xml
```

Answer (score 5):

The JAXB API is an unfortunate external dependency of jOOQ, which we've been trying to remove step by step in recent versions. We've already removed the JAXB implementation dependency, but the API, we still depend on in various parts of jOOQ.

It should be possible to use jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator without explicitly putting the JAXB API on the classpath also in JDK 11+. I've created an issue to resolve this particular problem: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9723

The `MiniJAXB` class is already a workaround to avoid depending on the JAXB implementation. jOOQ should also avoid depending on the JAXB API, in the future.

For the time being, [michalk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59703860/521799) is the only viable one if you do not want to use Maven or Gradle to resolve your transitive dependencies for you.